# Google map not rendering properly when called via function in a for loop

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, google-maps-api-3, razor-pages

I'm making a project in ASP.NET MVC Core and I am trying to create a list with coordinates and display a google map pin next to it.

The map is rendering but the it is greyed out/blank.

My code for the list with the maps

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Coordinates)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @{
            int count = 0;
        }
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="@count" style="height:400px;width:700px;"></div>
                    <script type="text/javascript">myMap('@count', @item.Coordinates)</script>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Coordinates)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Coordinates">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Coordinates">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Coordinates">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            count++;
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The JS function I'm using. It is loaded in `head` together with my API key

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myMap(divId, coord) {
            var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(coord);
            var mapProp = { center: myCenter, zoom: 12, scrollwheel: false, draggable: true, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(divId), mapProp);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: myCenter });
            marker.setMap(map);
        }
    </script>
```

And this is my result.

[image: map not rendering properly]

When I am not loading the map in a for loop and using the script but with hardcoded parameters it works fine.

```
<div id="googleMap" style="height:400px;width:100%;"></div>
<script>
        function myMap() {
            var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(@Model.Coordinates);
            var mapProp = { center: myCenter, zoom: 12, scrollwheel: false, draggable: true, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: myCenter });
            marker.setMap(map);
        }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&callback=myMap"></script>
```

[image: map rendering properly]

I cant figure out what I'm doing wrong, I have been looking but cannot find any answers. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can't start an id with a number. Your loop looks like it is naming the div's ids with just a number. Try prefixing the number with map_, for example.

Comment: Yep, sure I will give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you initialise your maps after the Google Maps API is loaded. To do that just point the `callback` part of the google's url to the function that will handle that (see example below).

Also as Lee stated in his comment do not use numbers as element ids. Lee's suggestion to use a prefix is spot on and you should consider using it.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Coordinates)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @{
            int count = 0;
        }
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="map" id="map_@count" style="height:400px;width:700px;" data-coord="@item.Coordinates"></div>
                    <!-- REMOVED script here and added more data to the div element above -->
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Coordinates)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Coordinates">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Coordinates">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Coordinates">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            count++;
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
  // this function will be called by google's api once loaded
  function loaded() {
    // assuming each map container has a class "map",
    let maps = document.querySelectorAll('.map');
    maps.forEach(map => initMap(map));
  }
  function initMap(map) {
    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(map.dataset.coord); // retrieving coords from data attribute
    var mapProp = { center: myCenter, zoom: 12, scrollwheel: false, draggable: true, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(map, mapProp);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: myCenter });
    marker.setMap(map);
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&callback=loaded"></script>
```

Edit: Have a look at below snippet. I haven't spotted before that the coords have to be passed as numbers.

```js
let maps = document.querySelectorAll('.map')

function loaded() {
  maps.forEach(map => initMap(map))
}

function initMap(element) {
  let xy = element.dataset.coords.split(',').map(a => parseFloat(a))
  let center = new google.maps.LatLng(xy[0], xy[1])
  let props = { center: center, zoom: 12, scrollwheel: false, draggable: true, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
  let map = new google.maps.Map(element, props);
  let marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: center });
  marker.setMap(map);
}
```

```css
.map {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!-- The British Museum -->
<div class="map" data-coords="51.5145532,-0.1167918"></div>
<!-- Castello Sforzesco -->
<div class="map" data-coords="45.4636261,9.1714131"></div>
<!-- Nordscheleife -->
<div class="map" data-coords="50.3341015,6.9404738"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=loaded" async defer></script>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer! I think this looks like a more elegant solution.

So I've tried this but it is resulting in that the maps are still grey. I'm not well versed in JS but maybe there is some conflict of passing "map" as a parameter to initMap when there is a ```var map``` in the function? I assume that I dont have to pass the div id explicitly to ```new google.maps.Map``` when its called via the container class?

Comment: I tried changing the ```var = map``` to "mapper" but to no avail.

Comment: I will try this when I get home. However I don't think that you have to pass the coords as numbers, at least it should work when I pass it directly from the model since it does when I do it for a single map in my example.. edit: although maybe it is different now that we put them in the div as an attribute?

Comment: Your edit works magic! (after I removed the 's' after the call for 'element.dataset.coords.split...') :) Good job man and thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you get the cordinates before the map is initialized? try make the api call inside OnMapReady event

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: You were right in the being something wrong with the coordinates, but the edited answer from @siaznik worked :)